# Div class change not showing during .each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a javascript function triggered by a button click. I add a class to an element before going into an 'each' loop.

When running the code in the page, I do not see the change. But if I pause the code in the debugger, I do.

The code is set up like this:

```
$("#btnApplyDefaults").on('click',
        function (e) {
    $('#loader').addClass("loading-page");
    $('#pricingSheetItems tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {
        // Do some stuff
    });
    $('#loader').removeClass("loading-page");
});
```

If I run this with data that takes a long time to run, I never see the loading image. But if I have a breakpoint, and walk through I see the image.

Here's the class:

```
div.loading-page {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    background-image: url("../../dist/img/loading.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
```

I'm assigning it to this div:

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="" id="loader"></div>
```

Comment: *When running the code in the page, I do not see the change. But if I pause the code in the debugger, I do.* Because the code between adding and removing the class run so quickly that it happens before the UI can be updated. When you are in the debugger, you are manually slowing it down. This is normal behavior. The speed at which the JavaScript runtime can process code is not synchronous with the speed with which the browser updates the UI. Voting to close the question as off-topic because there really isn't a problem here.

Comment: Try moving your removeClass() line into the filter function you created. It might be getting called too quickly

Comment: The code runs for about 30 seconds. Also, the filter function is an `.each`. Wouldn't putting my removeClass in that mean it gets called repeatedly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the behavior is normal and there doesn't seem to be an actual problem.

Comment: As written, `removeClass` and `addClass` run at almost the same time. As pointed out, it is behaving as expected. You might want to use `setTimeout` if you really need that image to show. Otherwise use async (Like promises) so that everything is ran sequentially

Comment: Take a look into how the event loop works. Once you understand that, you'll know why this code doesn't work as you expected.

Comment: Don't use $.each(), that runs asynchronously and the next statement gets executed before the $.each() finishes. You can use for(var index in items) { ... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your code runs synchronously, meaning that it completes all of it before your UI responds. You add the loading class at the beginning, do some operations, and remove the class, all before the UI can respond.

If you want your UI to update, you can add a minor pause via setTimeout:

```
 $("#btnApplyDefaults").on('click',
        function (e) {
    $('#loader').addClass("loading-page");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#pricingSheetItems tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {
            // Do some stuff
        });
        $('#loader').removeClass("loading-page");
    }, 0);
});
```

This should show the loading class. I suspect it won't animate though, because your page will be busy doing computations. You should look into using WebWorkers or some sort of asynchronous worker for a better user experience.